# how to read text file in server from client in windows application using C# 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, client-server

how to read text file in server from client in windows application using C# 4.0

and display the same in textbox in the client application

able to read the text locally and print the same in textbox

but from server how to do?

below is the code i tried for local file

```
string line;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int counter = 0;

using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path))
{
  while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
         if (line.Contains(searchstring))
          {
               if (line.Contains(searchfromdate)) //|| line.Contains(searchtodate)) 
                  {
                        sb.AppendLine(line.ToString());
                        counter++;
                  }
          }
      }
}

ResultTextBox.Text = sb.ToString();
CountLabel.Text = counter.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access files on a server you need 2 things

- Make sure your are using aa user that hass permission to access the file
- Set the server address path as \servername1\Folder\file.txt

so using your code you would have to have something like

```
string line;
string path = @"\\server1\TextFolder\Text.txt";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int counter = 0;

using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path))
{
  while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
         if (line.Contains(searchstring))
          {
               if (line.Contains(searchfromdate)) //|| line.Contains(searchtodate)) 
                  {
                        sb.AppendLine(line.ToString());
                        counter++;
                  }
          }
      }
}

ResultTextBox.Text = sb.ToString();
CountLabel.Text = counter.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** you need to `Share` the folder in server machine and provide `Read` permission to the users who want to access it from remotly.

**2.** Get the `IPAddress` or `Hostname` of the Server machine so that you can access the shared folders.

**3.** Now prepare the filepath as below:

Example: if ServerName is `MyServer123` and FolderName is `MyFolder` FileName is `myFile.txt`

your path should be `"\\MyServer123\MyFolder\MyFile.txt"`

**Complete Code:**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int counter = 0;
String path=@"\\MyServer123\MyFolder\MyFile.txt";
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(path))
{
  if (line.Contains(searchstring) && (line.Contains(searchfromdate)))
  {
    sb.AppendLine(line);
    counter++;
  }
}
ResultTextBox.Text = sb.ToString();
CountLabel.Text = counter.ToString();
```